# Varias funções que farão a mesma coisa

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho a seguinte função

```
function about_about(){
    $this->render();
}
```

Porém, tenho outras 100 páginas, que apenas terão o `render()`, como eu posso fazer uma função apenas pra economizar código e tempo? Onde eu defina as páginas que serão exibidas e dou o `render()`, lembrando que `about_about`, neste exemplo, é o nome da página que vem pela `url`, no caso, o nome do método.

Comment: Você quer chamar o mesmo método por URL diferentes? Tipo criar um controller genérico?

Comment: Cara, não manjo de PHP não.. mas não existe a possibilidade de você criar uma classe, que possui esse método que é comum a todos e fazer todas as outras classes herdarem a primeira não?

Comment: Isso mesmo Alan, quero chamar vários métodos com o mesmo fim... porque todos eles vão renderizar, ex: function x(){ render(); } function y(){ render(); }...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, utilizando o conceito de [Herança de Objetos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.inheritance.php), que é parte do modelo de  [orientação a objetos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.php).

Para criar a herança de classes você pode fazer assim:

Cria um arquivo, por exemplo: `comum.php`, com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php
class base  extends CI_Controller {
    function render() {
        echo 'Comum a todas as classes.';
    }
}
```

No seu controller, você usará:

```
<?php
include 'comum.php'; // incluir o arquivo da classe base
$about = new base();
$about->render();
```

O resultado será a saída do método que foi extendido da classe base:

```
Comum a todas as classes.
```

Espero ter ajudado e desejo boa sorte em seu projeto!

Comment: O que eu queria evitar, é ter que repetir varias vezes o mesmo código, mudando apenas o nome da função... por isso, mas acho que não tem outra forma né?

Comment: Editei a resposta, se consegui lhe entender direito, acho que agora tem o que você está procurando lá.

Comment: estou usando o CodeIgniter